# How can a receiver contract know the original sender with an ERC223 tokenFallback?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-223

When we make a token tx to a receiver contract, the sender has to use the transfer function in the token contract first before being able to send the tokens to the receiver contract.

Sender --> Token Contract --> Receiver Contract

Does this mean the `msg.sender` the receiver contract will get is the token address? If so, how can a receiver contract know the original sender address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that `msg.sender` in the receiver will be the address of a token contract.  This is why the first parameter to `tokenFallback` is the address of the original sender: for a compliant ERC223 token, the receiver knows the original sender by this first parameter.

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223 mentions these points:

> Contract to work with tokens
>
> `function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _value, bytes _data)` A
>   function for handling token transfers, which is called from the token
>   contract, when a token holder sends tokens. `_from` is the address of
>   the sender of the token,_value is the amount of incoming tokens, and
>   _data is attached data similar to msg.data of Ether transactions. It works by analogy with the fallback function of Ether transactions and
>   returns nothing.
>
> NOTE: msg.sender will be a token-contract inside the tokenFallback
>   function. It may be important to filter which tokens are sent (by
>   token-contract address). The token sender (the person who initiated
>   the token transaction) will be _from inside the tokenFallback function.